# Ffmpeg and ffprobe not showing subtitles stream in m3u8 file

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, m3u8, subtitle, ffprobe

I'm trying to get an mp4 video from a m3u8 playlist file (in simple HLS), with audio, video and subtitles.

I've managed to extract the video and audio stream because they are relatively easy: the input m3u8, according to ffprobe, contains 3 different programs, and the third program (called Program 2) is the one I need, because it contains both the highest quality video and the English highest quality audio.

So, what I really am doing is

```
ffmpeg -i "blahblah.m3u8" -c copy -map 0:p:2:v:0 -map 0:p:2:a:m:language:eng -map 0:s:0 "output.mp4"
```

Which means: select the first video stream for the third (index 2) program and the English language audio stream from the same third (index 2) program.

My problem is: I can't seem to find the two subtitles streams.
The m3u8 has two subtitles: English and Spanish, as you can see in the m3u8 itself

```
#EXTM3U
# Created with Bento4 mp4-hls.py version 1.2.0r637

#EXT-X-VERSION:4

# Subtitles
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,GROUP-ID="subtitles",NAME="English",LANGUAGE="en",URI="subtitles/en/subtitles.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,GROUP-ID="subtitles",NAME="Español",LANGUAGE="es",URI="subtitles/es/subtitles.m3u8"

# Audio
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="audio_aac",NAME="Français",LANGUAGE="fra",AUTOSELECT=YES,DEFAULT=YES,URI="audio/aac/fra/stream.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="audio_aac",NAME="English",LANGUAGE="eng",AUTOSELECT=YES,URI="audio/aac/eng/stream.m3u8"

# Media Playlists
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=2198120,BANDWIDTH=2416640,CODECS="avc1.4D401F,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=1280x720,AUDIO="audio_aac",SUBTITLES="subtitles"
media-1/stream.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=1001663,BANDWIDTH=1102896,CODECS="avc1.42C01E,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=640x360,AUDIO="audio_aac",SUBTITLES="subtitles"
media-2/stream.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=4007581,BANDWIDTH=4391894,CODECS="avc1.4D4029,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=1920x1080,AUDIO="audio_aac",SUBTITLES="subtitles"
media-3/stream.m3u8
```

I thought it was easy: I added a `-map 0:s:0` to get the first subtitles, but ffmpeg told me that there's no stream named like that.

Then I ran ffprobe, which tells me there are no subtitles streams for him:

```
ffprobe "blahblah.m3u8" -show_streams -select_streams s
```

[You can find here all the streams which the ffprobe command shows](https://pastebin.com/YJQqfbFF). There are lots of video and audio streams, but there are no subtitles streams.

Why don't ffmpeg and ffprobe find the subtitles streams? Is it because they are split in a different m3u8 playlist file?

Comment: Add `-strict experimental` to the `ffprobe` command.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sw = [Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
$files = Get-ChildItem ${Get-Location}
$loco = Get-Location
$p1 = Join-Path -Path $loco -ChildPath "/out"
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $p1



function lnCodeTransform {
    param( $String )
    switch ($String)
    {
        "jpn" {"jp"}
        "eng" {"en"}
        "esp" {"es"}
        "fra" {"fr"}
        "deu" {"de"}
        default {$String}
    }
}


function lnNameTransform {
    param( $String )
    switch ($String)
    {
        "jpn" {"Japanese"}
        "eng" {"English"}
        "esp" {"Spanish"}
        "fra" {"French"}
        "deu" {"German"}
        default {$String}
    }
}


foreach ($f in $files){ 
    if ($f.Name -eq "out"){
        continue;
    }
    $p2 = Join-Path -Path $loco -ChildPath "/out/" | Join-Path -ChildPath $f
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $p2/audio
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $p2/video
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $p2/subtitle
    $sb = [System.Text.StringBuilder]::new();
    [void]$sb.AppendLine( '#EXTM3U' )
    [void]$sb.AppendLine( '#EXT-X-VERSION:3' )
    #[void]$sb.AppendLine( '#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=800000,RESOLUTION=640x360' )
    #[void]$sb.AppendLine( '360p.m3u8' )
    

    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $p2
    $resStr = ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=height -of csv=s=x:p=0 $f.FullName;
    $res = [convert]::ToInt32($resStr)
    $audioTracks = ffprobe $f.FullName -show_entries stream=index:stream_tags=language,title -select_streams a -of compact=p=0:nk=1 
    $audioTracks = $audioTracks.split("\r")
    foreach($audio in $audioTracks) {
        $splited = $audio.split("|");
        $ID = $splited[0]
        $audioName = $splited[1];
        $title = $splited[2];
        ffmpeg -i $f.FullName -ss 0 -y -map 0:$ID -start_number 0 -acodec aac -b:a 320k -ac 2 -f segment -segment_time 10 -segment_list_size 0 -segment_list out/$f/audio/audio_"$ID.m3u8" -segment_format mpegts out/$f/audio/"audio_$ID""_%d.ts"
        $name = lnNameTransform($audioName)
        $code = lnCodeTransform($audioName)
        [void]$sb.AppendLine( "#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID=`"aac`",LANGUAGE=`"$code`",NAME=`"$name ($title)`",DEFAULT=NO,AUTOSELECT=NO,URI=`"audio/audio_$ID.m3u8`"" )
    }
    $subTracks = ffprobe $f.FullName -show_entries stream=index:stream_tags=language,title -select_streams s -of compact=p=0:nk=1 
    $subTracks = $subTracks.split("\r")
    foreach($subtitle in $subTracks) {
        $splited = $subtitle.split("|");
        $ID = $splited[0];
        $subName = $splited[1];
        $title = $splited[2];
        ffmpeg -i $f.FullName -ss 0 -map 0:$ID -f segment -segment_time 10 -segment_list_size 0 -segment_list out/$f/subtitle/sub_"$ID.m3u8" -segment_format webvtt -scodec webvtt out/$f/subtitle/"sub_$ID%d.vtt"
        $name = lnNameTransform($subName)
        $code = lnCodeTransform($subName)
        [void]$sb.AppendLine( "#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,GROUP-ID=`"subs`",LANGUAGE=`"$code`",NAME=`"$name ($title)`",FORCED=NO,AUTOSELECT=NO,URI=`"subtitle/sub_$ID.m3u8`"" )
    }

    [void]$sb.AppendLine( '#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1400000,CODECS="avc1.4d4015,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=842x480,AUDIO="aac",SUBTITLES="subs"' )
    [void]$sb.AppendLine( 'video/480p.m3u8' )
    #ffmpeg -i $f.FullName -c:a copy -vf scale=w=640:h=360:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -c:a aac -ar 48000  -rc cqp -qp_p 0 -qp_i 1 -profile:v main -crf 20 -sc_threshold 0 -g 48 -keyint_min 48 -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type vod  -b:v 800k -maxrate 856k -bufsize 1200k -b:a 96k -hls_segment_filename out/$f/360p_%03d.ts out/$f/360p.m3u8 -vf scale=w=842:h=480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -c:a aac -ar 48000 -gpu 1 -c:v h264_amf -rc cqp -qp_p 0 -qp_i 1 -profile:v main -crf 20 -sc_threshold 0 -g 48 -keyint_min 48 -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type vod -b:v 1400k -maxrate 1498k -bufsize 2100k -b:a 128k -hls_segment_filename out/$f/480p_%03d.ts out/$f/480p.m3u8 -vf  scale=w=1280:h=720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -c:a aac -ar 48000 -gpu 1 -c:v h264_amf -rc cqp -qp_p 0 -qp_i 1 -profile:v main -crf 20 -sc_threshold 0 -g 48 -keyint_min 48 -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type vod -b:v 2800k -maxrate 2996k -bufsize 4200k -b:a 128k -hls_segment_filename out/$f/720p_%03d.ts out/$f/720p.m3u8 -vf  scale=w=1920:h=1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -c:a aac -ar 48000 -gpu 1 -c:v h264_amf -rc cqp -qp_p 0 -qp_i 1 -profile:v main -crf 20 -sc_threshold 0 -g 48 -keyint_min 48 -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type vod -b:v 5000k -maxrate 5350k -bufsize 7500k -b:a 192k -hls_segment_filename out/$f/1080p_%03d.ts out/$f/1080p.m3u8
    #ffmpeg -hwaccel auto -hwaccel_device 0 -i $f.FullName -c:v h264 -profile:v main -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -filter:v scale=360:640 -ar 48000  -rc cqp -qp_p 0 -qp_i 1 -profile:v main -crf 23 -sc_threshold 0 -g 48 -b:v 800k -maxrate 856k -bufsize 1200k -b:a 96k  -keyint_min 4 -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_playlist_type vod  -hls_list_size 0 -f hls -hls_segment_filename out/$f/360p_%03d.ts out/$f/360p.m3u8 
    #ffmpeg -hwaccel auto -hwaccel_device 0 -i $f.FullName -c:v h264 -profile:v main -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -filter:v scale=360:640 -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls -hls_segment_filename out/$f/360p_%03d.ts out/$f/360p.m3u8 
    #ffmpeg -i $f.FullName -c:v h264 -crf 23 -b:v 1200k -minrate 500k -maxrate 2100k -profile:v main -pix_fmt yuv420p -y -filter:v scale=-2:480 -map 0:v -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls -hls_segment_filename out/$f/video/480p_%03d.ts out/$f/video/480p.m3u8
    ffmpeg -i $f.FullName -c:v h264_qsv -preset slow -global_quality 30 -look_ahead 1 -profile:v main -level:v 4.1 -rc:v vbr_hq -rc-lookahead:v 32 -pix_fmt yuv420p -y -filter:v scale=-2:480 -map 0:v -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls -hls_segment_filename out/$f/video/480p_%03d.ts out/$f/video/480p.m3u8
    If($res -ge 720) {
        #ffmpeg -i $f.FullName -c:v h264_qsv -crf 23 -b:v 2400k -minrate 1200k -maxrate 4200k -profile:v main -pix_fmt yuv420p -filter:v scale=-2:720 -map 0:v -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls -hls_segment_filename out/$f/video/720p_%03d.ts out/$f/video/720p.m3u8
        ffmpeg -i $f.FullName -c:v h264_qsv -preset slow -global_quality 28 -look_ahead 1 -profile:v main -level:v 4.1 -rc:v vbr_hq -rc-lookahead:v 32 -pix_fmt yuv420p -filter:v scale=-2:720 -map 0:v -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls -hls_segment_filename out/$f/video/720p_%03d.ts out/$f/video/720p.m3u8
        [void]$sb.AppendLine( '#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=2800000,CODECS="avc1.4d4015,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=1280x720,AUDIO="aac",SUBTITLES="subs"' )
        [void]$sb.AppendLine( 'video/720p.m3u8' )
    }   
    If($res -ge 900) {
        #ffmpeg -i $f.FullName -c:v h264 -crf 30 -b:v 4800k -minrate 2000k -maxrate 8400k -profile:v main -pix_fmt yuv420p -filter:v scale=-2:1080 -map 0:v -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls -hls_segment_filename out/$f/video/1080p_%03d.ts out/$f/video/1080p.m3u8
        ffmpeg -i $f.FullName -c:v h264_qsv -preset slow -global_quality 26 -look_ahead 1 -profile:v main -level:v 4.1 -rc:v vbr_hq -rc-lookahead:v 32 -pix_fmt yuv420p -filter:v scale=-2:1080 -map 0:v -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls -hls_segment_filename out/$f/video/1080p_%03d.ts out/$f/video/1080p.m3u8

        [void]$sb.AppendLine( '#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=5000000,CODECS="avc1.4d4015,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=1920x1080,AUDIO="aac",SUBTITLES="subs"' )
        [void]$sb.AppendLine( 'video/1080p.m3u8' )
    }
    
    $p3 = Join-Path -Path $p2 -ChildPath "/index.m3u8"
    #echo $index | Out-File -Encoding UTF8 -LiteralPath $p3
    echo $sb.ToString()
    [System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($p3, $sb.ToString().Trim().replace("`r`n", "`n"))
}
$sw.Stop()
echo $sw.Elapsed
```

This is my script  that i use  to convert files  to  HLS and it generates the index.m3u8 file.   yes you will need to edit the index  but it does all the work.   also this script uses  Intel gpu.   you can remove the _qsv to make it work on any CPU